# No return data from PreparedStatement query

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I am trying to do a SELECT using `PreparedStatement`, but not getting any results back, despite the data being present.  If I use `Statement` instead, I get the desired results, so not sure why I don't get anything with the `PreparedStatement`.
Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
String species = "Snail";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("Select * from lifeforms where species=?",PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
preparedStatement.setString(1, species);
preparedStatement.execute();
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Also - I have tried just

```
resultSet = preparedStatement.execute();
```

But this won't compile, saying I must change `resultSet` to expect a boolean value.

Any insights into this would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if this is something obvious, but I have read the docs until I am almost unconscious, and I'm only just learning java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah so I have finally found the answer to this question - in case anyone else is stuck on the same thing..

The `execute()` method has no return value, although the compiler was suggesting it expected a boolean return value. Maybe it just returns true or false for successful or not?

The `executeUpdate()` method returns an int value of the number of records updated/inserted or deleted.

To get the result set of a query statement (e.g. Select * from someTable), use the
`ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery()` method. 
This will return the actual query results into a ResultSet variable.

Answer (score 2):

The `execute()` functon returns a boolean value so u won't be able to put this in an object of resultset, if you want to execute a select statement you have to use `executeQuery()`.